# How to play videos from remote URL using AVPLayer in Swift 2

Tags: swift, swift2, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

Im trying to use AVPlayer for video files, I upload some videos in a public folder in googleDrive, dropbox, riouxsvn and github... none of them can be played.

Otherwise I found samples that works and I noticed that the videos that works are those that can be played in the browser automatically.

The player is not the real problem... this issue is more related with the videos. If I clic any url from the ones that can be played the video instantly starts in the browser... If I clic on the urls that can NOT be played you will see that the video doesnt start, I have to clic it to play (dropbox and google drive) or in riouxsvn the video starts to download.

So I do not know and I can not find on the internet yet how to solve this. Do you have any idea how and where should I upload the videos so it can be played on the device?

```
@IBAction func playVideoTest(sender: AnyObject) {

    //Video URLs that can be played
    //let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://jplayer.org/video/m4v/Big_Buck_Bunny_Trailer.m4v")!
    //let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")!

    //Video URLs that can NOT be played
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://svn.riouxsvn.com/salsa4allmedia/Videos/SampleVideo.mp4")!
    //let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkjwajuo7r1mqox/SampleVideo.mp4?dl=0")!
    //let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1tAk1RMaHu0T1dVNWFYS1ExS0k")!
    //let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://github.com/dervatii/SalsaMedia/blob/master/SampleVideo.MOV")!

    var player = AVPlayer()

    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerController.player = player

    self.presentViewController(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

[Check the result showed in the simulator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twaqB.png)

Answer (score -1):

**In swift 3**

```
   @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: AnyObject) {

                let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
                let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
                let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                playerLayer.frame = vedioPlayer.bounds
                vedioPlayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                player.play()
}
```